# Swift background music that pauses when apple music/ spotify is playing in background

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit, xcode8

I want my background song to stop playing when music from another app is playing. Such as apple music or Spotify. If you download color switch you'll know what I mean. Currently Im using the method below but my background  song doesn't stop it mixes with the playing music.(This method kinda works with apple music but not Spotify). I want my song to play indefinitely until other music is playing in background and for it to start again when the other music is paused.(Try it with color Switch)

Thanks

```
 func setUpAudio() {
        //dead = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(SoundFile.dead, waitForCompletion: true)
       // buttonpress = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(SoundFile.button, waitForCompletion: true)

        if GameScene.backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
            let backgroundMusicURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: SoundFile.BackgroundMusic, withExtension: nil)

            do {
                let theme = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: backgroundMusicURL!)
                GameScene.backgroundMusicPlayer = theme

            } catch {
                // couldn't load file :[
            }

            GameScene.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        }

        if !GameScene.backgroundMusicPlayer.isPlaying {
            GameScene.backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
        }
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        /*try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers
        )*/

        do { try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) }
        catch let error as NSError { print(error) }
        //s audio from other sessions to be ducked (reduced in volume) while audio from this session plays
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're session category allows mixing, which is not what you want. Try using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` or `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`, as these won't allow your app to mix audio with other apps.

[See the docs for more info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/audio_session_categories)

Comment: I tried both. They don't give me the result I explained above.

Comment: I want my music to stop not the third party's.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but did you ever figure out why it wouldn't stop? I'm having the same issue, using AudioKit.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the AVAudioSession to active.

```
    let _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    let _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```